# Function to handle when user choose to cancel Game Center login?

Tags: ipad, uialertview, game-center

I am developing an iPad game. I have this situation. When the user/player's game center account is not signed in, it will prompt an alert box, to let player choose, either to:

1. Login existing account
2. Create new account
3. Cancel

I am interested on 3rd option ("cancel"). How to handle or assign a function, when user click the "cancel" option. I tried this:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 2){ 
        NSLog(@"Cancel called");
    ....
```

But not working. Is there any other solution?

THanks

Answer (score 3):

This is probably extremely late and no one cares anymore, but the way to handle this is in your Game Center authentication handler. Specifically, if the user selects 'cancel', you'll get a `GKErrorCancelled` code:

```
- (void) authenticate {

    GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) {

        if(error.code == GKErrorCancelled) {
            //this is the case you're interested in
        }

        if(localPlayer.authenticated) {
            //rock on
        }
    }];
}
```

Again, this post is probably ancient history by now, but, hope that helps in any case :)